# C# ADO.NET writing primary key before foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, ado.net

I'm working on an application that gets userdata from a REST-Server and writes it to a local database by using C# and ADO.NET(about 100000 rows). The database is MYSQL.
To do that I created two tables. 
TABLE A and 
TABLE B

Table B has a foreign key reference to Table A.
When syncing the data, I receive a foreign key error, because the data is not fully written to Table A when the applications tries to get the foreign key.

I'm not using a DataAdapter or Dataset just plain ADO.NET. --> It should be as fast and simple as possible.

It works when I make  a small delay after writing to Table A and before writing to Table B, but that's only a temporary solution and not very reliable.

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(userInsert, connection))
    {        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
Thread.Sleep(600);
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(cardInsert, connection))
    {        
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }    
}
```

I also put the two transactions in one transactions, but without success.

Does anyone have a better solution ?

Comment: Do not structure your code like that. Open the connection, create the transaction, insert _all_ the data (users and cards), commit the transaction, close the connection. Do note that `ExecuteNonQuery` does return a `int` value of the rows affected. In an insert query would be the rows inserted (expected value greater than cero).

Comment: I tried that just like you describe it, but without success

Comment: Without success... please do provide the error or missbehaviour you face. Check the [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, here is the error message that I receive: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure to insert the data to both tables in one round trip?